# Is it possible to use python scripts inside my react native app?

Tags: python, node.js, react-native

I'm currently writing android apps with react-native. But now im faced with the following problem:
Is it possible to use a python function inside a react-native app (on android) without using a external server like aws lambda?
Converting the code with for example transcrypt doesn't seem to solve my problem.
NodeJs can run python scripts, and I can use nodejs in react-native applications. Could this be a possible solution?

I would be glad for some advices.

Comment: What type of python script? What a python script can make that a Javascript can't?

Comment: I'm currently working on an ai analysing pictures. It works without machine learning and should work without internet connection.

Comment: It's much easier to make an API in python to consume your AI than a AI mobile.

Comment: Maybe that's the best approach, thanks!